# How does nmap determine if it's running HTTP service on a port? Fails here

Tags: nmap

I'm running apache on `192.168.56.178`, which listens on port `80, 8090 and 8095` (configured as `<VirtualHost *>`).

Now If I open my browser and point to any of those 3 ports, e.g `192.168.56.178:8095` I will get a `It works` page.

Then I try to determine which port runs HTTP service with nmap,

```
%> nmap -p 80,8090,8095 192.168.56.178 

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2013-11-01 17:00 CST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.178
Host is up (0.00025s latency).
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
8090/tcp open  unknown
8095/tcp open  unknown
```

From the result, nmap cannot determine ports other than 80. Why is that?

Can I fix it?

Comment: nmap only does service detection if you pass the `-sV` flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`nmap` defaults to the `-sS` option if a scan type is not specified. The `-sS` flag is a simple `SYN` scan to check the status of the port. No advanced fingerprinting is done to determine the service running on the port. In this mode, `nmap` merely looks up the most common service running on the particular port using the [nmap-services](http://nmap.org/book/nmap-services.html) file and displays it under the services header.

If you want more accurate fingerprinting to be done, try running `nmap` with the `-sV` or `-A` flag for version detection and aggressive mode respectively. The `-sV` version detection flag will instruct nmap to perform more intrusive scan types like making HTTP request to the port and reading the banner information for example. The `-A` flag goes a step further and attempts to scan the port with [NSE](http://nmap.org/book/nse.html) scripts. Both the `-sV` and `-A` flag *should* identify Apache running on ports 8090 and 8095.

Comment: If `-sV` is not specified, nmap generate the `SERVICE` tab with port specifications? e.g using data from `/etc/services`

Comment: @warl0ck No. `nmap` does not use the `/etc/services` file for port specifications. Instead, nmap maintains a `nmap-services` file. In my Fedora 19 machine, the file is located at `/usr/share/nmap/nmap-services`. The file format is the same as the `/etc/services` file though, so customizing it is very possible.

Comment: @warl0ck In addition, a custom `nmap-services` file can be passed as an option using the `--servicedb` flag.

Comment: `-A` enables lots of things: service detection, OS fingerprinting, NSE script scanning, and traceroute.